# How do I call a defined procedure within another def procedure? - Python

Tags: python, procedure

I don't understand the basic mechanics of calling a procedure for use in defining a second one. I'm struggling to conceptualize a simple procedure calling another in trying to figure it out on my own and I've gotten to a point in my self-paced lessons where it would be useful.

Information on this is hard to find (perhaps I'm not using the right keywords) and the only examples I've seen were way too complicated for me to break down. If you have any internet literature I can read, I'll accept that.

How can I def a procedure second and call procedure first within it? I know that {} are for dictionaries, [] for lists (more or less), and () for strings (more or less) at this point.

Is there a rule I can follow? Can I call the first procedure anywhere, like in a for loop (for e in first:) or an if statement (if first:)? Having trouble conceptualizing this one. I've spent hours on this playing with the code, trying to figure it out with no luck. Please help break it down for me!

Comment: Are you talking about a particular language?

Comment: @WaffleStealer654 Sorry! Yes, totally. Python.

Comment: By procedure do you mean function? I figured that's what you meant, but then I got to the paragraph about {}, [], (), and after that I lost all concept of what you are asking, sorry. You mention you've been playing with code for hours, maybe if you shared some of the code as an illustration that would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call a function nested in an if statement and you can call a function inside a loop. Nobody thinks about "rules" like these when they program. After you play around with code, it'll become second nature.

```
def print_hello_world(): # first function
    print "hello world"

def in_an_if_statement(): # a function that uses first func in if statement
    if 1 == 1:
        print_hello_world()

def in_a_loop(): # a function that uses first func in a loop
    for i in range(3):
        print_hello_world()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    in_an_if_statement()
    print '----'
    in_a_loop()
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to tackle this with no actual code to work with, Jay! I think I understand most of this. Is it safe to say then that I can kind of stick a defined procedure just about anywhere I want, as long as I include the parenthetical part exactly as is in the def part? The problems I'm seeing in my online lessons want me to use the called procedure as a variable, I think, like `announce = print_hello_world()`, although I have seen one with `return print_hello_world()` that I can compare these with. I will have to do some research on that last one. Thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: I've just modified the first one in my python interpreter to:

`def print_hello_world():
    return "hello world"

def in_an_if_statement(number):
    if number >= 1:
        return print_hello_world()
    else:
        return "Sorry! Too small!"

print in_an_if_statement(4)
print in_an_if_statement(0)`

Beautiful. I think I get it now! Thanks so much!